# How much memory and time will be needed to populate List in Java

Tags: java

I'm new to Java. I need to develop Java Server Faces web page with Java List that will have one million string keys in it. My question is do you know how much time will be need to populate this list and how much memory will be needed on a server to store it? Can you give me some example from your experience?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: In Java, this kind of operation always takes 433 ms and uses 4397 kb.

Comment: Very few people will have such experience, because having one million strings on one page is ridiculous.

Comment: Do this write a Test class with main method that loops a million times and stores however long string you expect to a List. Do a getByte and measure length. Use JHAT, JMAP to see resource utilization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should be able to get it work on a standard machine with 1-2 GB of ram, shouldn't be an issue. One million string are not huge fro memory perspective.